# How to add a plus sign before an int in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to generate an output in a very specific format, and the positive ints must have a plus sign in front of them. I'm using numpy arrays and was trying stuff like:

```
    if(int(P[pnt])>0):
        P[pnt] += np.insert(P[pnt-1],0,"+")
```

But it never adds the plus as part of the number, but rather as a different instance..

I and also tried saving it in a different file and then modify it from there (using `re.sub()` etc...) but no luck :(

my output looks like this:

```
(+1 2 -4 +5 -3)
(+1 2 3 -5 4)
(+1 2 3 -4 5)
(+1 2 3 4 5)
```

and should look like this:

```
(+1 +2 -4 +5 -3)
(+1 +2 +3 -5 +4)
(+1 +2 +3 -4 +5)
(+1 +2 +3 +4 +5)
```

I can share the entire code if necessary...

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.format()` and the [Python Format mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).  You want the `+` *sign* option.

```
'{:+}'.format(3)  # "+3"
'{:+}'.format(-3) # "-3"
```

Could go nuts:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 2, -4, 5, -3])
print '(' + ' '.join('{:+}'.format(n) for n in a)) + ')'
# (+1 +2 -4 +5 -3)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! but when I try that I get this error: ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier. If I try to cast my array vars as ints it simply doesn't do a thing. I guess that because I'm reading those values off a file it thinks those are string? or maybe because of the "+" and "-" there are in my input?

Comment: Yeah you probably have the dtypes as strings. So you need to convert the dtype of the array. This should do it: `a = a.astype(int)`, or you could set the dtype when you create the array.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to the answer of Nick T:
You can edit the print options of numpy, so whenever you print a numpy array that formatting will take place.

```
In [191]: np.set_printoptions(formatter={'all':lambda x: '{:+}'.format(x)})

In [198]: np.random.random_integers(-5,5,(5,5))
Out[198]:
array([[+2, +2, +2, -4, +0],
       [-2, -1, +3, +5, -1],
       [-5, -2, -1, -3, +4],
       [+1, +3, -5, +3, -4],
       [+2, -1, +2, +5, +5]])
```

The `'all'`defines what types this formatting should be used for. The docstring of set_printoptions will tell you what you can set there for more specific formatting.

```
     - 'bool'
     - 'int'
     - 'timedelta' : a `numpy.timedelta64`
     - 'datetime' : a `numpy.datetime64`
     - 'float'
     - 'longfloat' : 128-bit floats
     - 'complexfloat'
     - 'longcomplexfloat' : composed of two 128-bit floats
     - 'numpy_str' : types `numpy.string_` and `numpy.unicode_`
     - 'str' : all other strings

 Other keys that can be used to set a group of types at once are::

     - 'all' : sets all types
     - 'int_kind' : sets 'int'
     - 'float_kind' : sets 'float' and 'longfloat'
     - 'complex_kind' : sets 'complexfloat' and 'longcomplexfloat'
     - 'str_kind' : sets 'str' and 'numpystr'
```

Comment: Thanks!! that's a great hint! unfortunately, like I mentioned above, I keep getting this error: ValueError: Sign not allowed in string format specifier. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on an environment where I can test it, but [numpy.insert](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) should be inserting objects along an axis, appending a new index/value before the one you select.

In your conditional statement instead, the true result could set P[pnt] equal to '+' + str(P[pnt]). You're looking for an array of strings in the end, yes?